# replace inheritance with generic extension method

Tags: c#

I created a class that inherits from `KeyedByTypeCollection` and extends it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyedbytypecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

`KeyedByTypeCollection` only has a `Find` method which returns `null` if no item is found. I prefer a `TryGetValue` method so I added one.

```
internal class TypeCollection<V> : KeyedByTypeCollection<V>
{
    public T ValueOrDefault<T>() where T : V
    {
        if (!Contains(typeof(T)))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        return (T)this[typeof(T)];
    }

    public bool TryGetValue<T>(out T value) where T : V
    {
        if (!Contains(typeof(T)))
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        value = (T)this[typeof(T)];
        return true;
    }
}
```

The thing is there is no reason for inheritance. I just want to extend an existing class. I started with these two extension methods

```
internal static class KeyedByTypeCollectionExtensions
{
    public static T ValueOrDefault<T>(this KeyedByTypeCollection<V> collection) where T : V
    {
        if (!collection.Contains(typeof(T)))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        return (T)collection[typeof(T)];
    }

    public static bool TryGetValue<T>(this KeyedByTypeCollection<V> collection, out T value) where T : V
    {
        if (!collection.Contains(typeof(T)))
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }

        value = (T)collection[typeof(T)];
        return true;
    }
}
```

but how do I setup these extension methods? What do I have to set for the generic type `V`?

Comment: What‘s the Problem with your actual implementation? And why do you prefer extension method?

Comment: @Sebi Because extending a collection when simple extension methods suffice is normally not a good idea. And the current extension methods will not compile.

Comment: Well I thought I should prefer composition over inheritance so I thoguth about creating extension methods instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to define `V`.

```
public static T ValueOrDefault<T,V>(this KeyedByTypeCollection<V> collection) where T : V
```

and

```
public static bool TryGetValue<T,V>(this KeyedByTypeCollection<V> collection, out T value) 
       where T : V
```

It will work nice with the `TryGetValue`, because the compiler will know which types are used, but for the `ValueOrDefault` you will have to set both of the types, which is a bit ugly.

Lets consider the following classes:

```
public class A { }
public class B : A { }
```

Then usage can be:

```
var myCollection = new KeyedByTypeCollection<A>();
myCollection.Add(new A());
myCollection.Add(new B());

myCollection.TryGetValue(out B b); // <-- Nice! :)
b = myCollection.ValueOrDefault<B,A>();  // <-- Ugly :(
```